# No resource found that matches the given name keeps showing

Tags: android

when am trying to put a background to the layout the app just stops and exit ("unfortunatly, xxxx has stopped working") although the splash and main layouts works fine but as soon as i enter a new layout ex: contact us page ) with no background the app works fine :S :S
here's the code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/ibg" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/au" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please show logcat error.

Comment: [2014-11-25 10:39:13 - SP] C:\workspace\SP\res\layout\au.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/ibg.gif').
[2014-11-25 10:39:13 - SP]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting another background and check if the problem still exists. I thing there is some problem with your files in drawable folder. Try not setting a .gif image as background and set a jpg or png image.

Comment: it worked ty :) but what could be the problem with the file :S :S

Comment: I think it is because of .gif image. Usually .gif images are not used to set as background(I think). Please accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks :)